# Multiple Repositories One Github Runner

Tags: github-actions

I have two repositories. They are deployed on my own physical hardware. I have a self-hosted runner also on my own hardware. Other than `Organization level runners` which I assume cost money because you have to be an organization, is there a way to have both of my repositories use the same runner? I assume I cant have 2 runners on the same machine, (port conflicts and all).

I suppose I could write a custom service that is triggered with a webhook, but just wanted to see if there was a way before I do all that work.

Comment: Did you try the [step by step](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/adding-self-hosted-runners#adding-a-self-hosted-runner-to-a-repository) from the Github Documentation, adding the same self-hosted runner to your 2 different repositories?

Comment: Yes, however when you try to run the configure script with the second repo, the runner complains about already being configured.

Comment: Creating an organization in Github is free. Create and organization and add your runners at the org level then share them between your repositories.